# Formatting a "corrupt SD card" fails - is the card dead?

Tags: external-sd, hardware, formatting

I have a no-brand-marked 32 GB "Micro SD HC" Card, which I'd been using with my Android 6.0.1-based phone.

Recently, the phone has been telling me the card is corrupt, and would not use it; and today I tried formatting it as the UI suggested. Well, the formatting app closed after a very long time with no progress beyond some point, and nothing seems to have changed - the card is still described as corrupt.

Is it necessarily the case that my card is dead, or could this possibly be a software issue?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely. If you had the card set to be read as internal storage, Android sets an encryption on it. After a factory reset, the keys change, and the card is permanently write-protected. I have had no luck reversing this on mine.

Regards.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about "read as internal storage". Also - I have not done a factory reset of anything (that I know of).

Comment: You may have been prompted to set the SD card to be encrypted to be read the same as the internal storage. Since you have no recollection of a factory reset, chances are the card is dead/dying.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your Android device to a pc, is the memory card visible?

If yes, chances are, your memory card can be formated or the contents be recovered using the Command Prompt.

Let's say, your sd card drive is E-drive, then use the Command line:
" chkdsk E: /f "

Hope this works. All the best!